# How to link another page using button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used a template from the web for a Login page, and I am not able to figure out how can I link this page to another when one clicks the 'Login' button. I have no knowledge of HTML and CSS or JS , so if anybody can guide me through this I'll be grateful.Its for a college project that has to be submitted tomorrow. Its not that I don't want to learn, but there was something else I was working on which didn't work out pretty well so I had to start this and I have only a day.

I was unable to paste the code here. SO here's the link : http://pastebin.com/pPS0Np8A

Comment: At least try to do your homework, then ask where you got stuck! (must be a hot topic, seen this question come by 3 times in the past half hour). PS, -1 for question and +1 for being honest.

Comment: I got stuck here only, the rest of it I've handled. I know this question may be very stupid but I have no idea at all of the HTML,CSS and JS that goes into it. I have to learn, and I will. But I also have to get this project done by tomorrow.

Comment: I'll help. What are you learning? ASP? Where does your data get sent to? What validates a valid user?

Comment: Thanks but Harshit's answer got it working. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Lol, I think (given the code in your login-page) you'll find there is a more logical solution for sending/submitting your user-credentials and acting upon them to a login ok/denied page..

Comment: No, I am not validating anything, although I had  a plan previously, but now, I am redirecting the user to the homepage irrespective of whether he inputs something in the field or puts anything.I just have to make a prototype, so its fine. :)

Comment: Ok, in that case, for the future readers, the answer was: simply set the `form`'s `action` attribute to the page you want to go to (and send the form's values). The form will take care of the rest.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because not having enough time to do your work by yourself is no reason to ask on Stack Overflow to have someone else do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="click"  onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www.google.com/&quot;); window.open(&quot;http://www.youtube.com/&quot;);" />
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this one works, but now the the Login button has lost its CSS properties

Comment: @Yankee Make sure you have set the correct id/class used by your button for CSS for this button as well. Something like `id="your_id_here"` or `class="your_class_here"`

Comment: Got the CSS working, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a Link when pressing the button, put an `<a>`-tag around your button and the LInk inside the `href` attribute:

```
<p><a href="http://www.linkToWhereYOuWantItTo.Go"><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just tried that, putting a link: http://www.google.com in it, didn't work. The page just refreshes. And then I put my actual target, 'Default5.aspx', still didn't work. Is it because I am redirecting to a .aspx page ?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work because it's of type `input` which like prevents the `<a>`-tag to link to another page. Either you change it to another Type or use JS: `window.open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])` [Klick here for more Information](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

using harshit's solution i added the id to restore css properties but if the css value is a class rather than an id just replace id= with class=.

```
 <input type="button" value="click" id="myCssClassId"  onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www.google.com/&quot;); window.open(&quot;http://www.youtube.com/&quot;);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So you were "*not able to figure out how can I **link this page to another when one clicks the 'Login' button***".

Simplified from the login-page you provided, you have the following code:

```
<form action="Default5.aspx" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <p><label for="email">E-mail address</label></p>
        <p><input type="email"
                    id="email"
                 value="mail@address.com" 
              required="required" />
        </p>

        <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
        <p><input type="password"
                    id="password"
                 value="password" />
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, note the `<input type="submit" value="Login" />`. Once you'll click that, the `form` will submit the data contained in it (the password and email).

When you submit a form, the form needs an address where it needs to send the data to. This is then also the page that is displayed ('redirected'). You set this simply with the form's `action` attribute, which is just an URL.

Just wanted to rectify this for future readers.

**EDIT:**

So, for example an exact image-search on google *could* work like:

```
<form method="GET"
      action="http://www.google.com/search"
      target="_BLANK"
    onsubmit="var e = this.getElementsByTagName('input');
              e[1].value= 'isz:ex,iszw:' + e[3].value
                        +       ',iszh:' + e[4].value;
              return true;
             "
><fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch" />
    <input type="hidden" id="tbs" name="tbs" />
    <p>Search Image: 
       <input type="text" name="q" value="search" />
    </p>
    <p>
       Width: <input type="text" value="32" /> px <br />
       Height: <input type="text" value="32" /> px <br />
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Example jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/47NKM/)

Here the `method` is changed from `POST` to `GET`. That way the values entered in the form are appended to the URL (so anyone can read them).

To close with a final example of how to open a *new blank page* I added the `target`-attribute, and pointed it to `_BLANK`.

The example's are intentionally kept simple, style and expand on them as you wish.